# NSWindowController: loadWindow loads window from nib but showWindow: does nothing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib, nswindowcontroller

I have an NSWindowController subclass called `_PreferencesWindowController` with the following implementation -

```
@synthesize window;

- (id)init {

 self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"PreferencesWindow"];
 if (!self) return nil;

 return self;
}
```

And I tried to show the window in `_PreferencesWindowController` by using the following code -

```
_preferencesWindowController = [[_PreferencesWindowController alloc] init];
[_preferencesWindowController showWindow:nil];
```

It does nothing, and I checked `_preferencesWindowController.window` is `nil` from the debugger.

However if I call `loadView` on `_preferencesWindowController` the window can be loaded and is visible; `_preferencesWindowController.window` is no longer nil-valued -

```
[_preferencesWindowController loadWindow];
```

I looked at Apple's documentation on NSWindowController it specifically says "you should never directly invoke `loadWindow`", instead `showWindow:` should be used. I'm wondering what I might have missed that resulted in the above-mentioned behaviour I have been seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I solved this by looking at the `NSWindowController` header file.

The problem is in my header file for _PreferencesWindowController -

```
@interface _PreferencesWindowController : NSWindowController <NSToolbarDelegate> {

    NSWindow *window;

}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

By removing the @property declaration and changing `NSWindow *window` ivar to `IBOutlet NSWindow *window`, `showWindow:` method now works without a glitch.

The property declaration must have resulted in an undefined behaviour in `showWindow:` method in `NSWindowController`'s implementation.

Comment: Declaring the property was not the problem, but synthesizing it might have been—NSWindowController already has an implementation for `window`, and it's more than a simple property accessor. Having the ivar is also wrong, regardless of whether you declare it with `IBOutlet` (which doesn't matter to the compiler or at run time), because NSWindowController already has an outlet ivar by that name. You should cut out both the ivar *and* the property.

Comment: You are right. My subclass sees the `window` ivar in Interface Builder regardless whether I've declared the ivar. And your suggestion solved another problem I had with `-[NSOpenPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:  completionHandler:]` Thanks! :)