# NSWindowController showWindow:nil does nothing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

Like in the title, `[myWindowController showWindow:nil]` doesn't work. Here are some facts you may need to know:

- My window controller: `KRAuthenticationWindowController`
- Interface builder file: `AuthenticationWindow.xib`
- File's Owner is `KRAuthenticationWindowController`
- `window` outlet is connected to the window
- Window's `delegate` is connected to File's Owner
- Window's `Visible at launch` is unchecked
- Window's `Release when closed` is also unchecked

My code is presented below:

```
// KRApplicationDelegate.m

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    KRAuthenticationWindowController *authWindowController = [[KRAuthenticationWindowController alloc] init];
    [authWindowController showWindow:nil];
    [[authWindowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}

// KRAuthenticationWindowController.m

- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"AuthenticationWindow"];
    if(!self) return nil;
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return self;
}

- (void)loadWindow {
    [super loadWindow];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.73 alpha:1]];
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)showWindow:(id)sender {
    [super showWindow:sender];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.window);
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

My console output:

```
2013-02-24 16:21:45.420 Application[3105:303] -[KRApplicationDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:]
2013-02-24 16:21:45.421 Application[3105:303] -[KRAuthenticationWindowController init]
2013-02-24 16:21:45.428 Application[3105:303] -[KRAuthenticationWindowController loadWindow]
2013-02-24 16:21:45.428 Application[3105:303] -[KRAuthenticationWindowController windowDidLoad]
2013-02-24 16:21:45.556 Application[3105:303] <NSWindow: 0x10016e860>
2013-02-24 16:21:45.556 Application[3105:303] -[KRAuthenticationWindowController showWindow:]
```

I think I'm just missing something important. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you have issue described in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539721/nswindowcontroller-loadwindow-loads-window-from-nib-but-showwindow-does-nothin

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try turning authWindowController into an instance variable. Currently, it's a local variable. When the local variable goes away, the window controller may get released and the window with it, so it never gets shown.

Comment: This can happend if you are using ARC, more details in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677043/nswindowcontrollers-window-released-immediately

Comment: Just ran into the same issue thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Haha I surprised myself into running in the exact same situation! On 10.11 beta, first I thought it was a bug in the beta :P How dumb; thanks for the answer!